# Android plot range tick labels and domain tick lables are not visible when upgraded to 0.9.8

Tags: android, android-studio, androidplot

I was using the library version 0.9.7  and everythng was working as expected. When I moved to 0.9.8, the range tick labels and domain tick lables became invisible. I have not done any other changes other than the library upgrade.

Please find my xml

```
<com.androidplot.xy.XYPlotZoomPan
            android:id="@+id/dynamicXYPlot0"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginBottom="10dp"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginLeft="10dp"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginRight="10dp"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginTop="10dp"
            androidplot.renderMode="use_background_thread"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            ap:backgroundColor="#00000000"
            ap:borderColor="#00000000"
            ap:label="Lead I     "
            ap:labelTextColor="#757575"
            ap:labelTextSize="15sp" />
```

And this is my plot initialization.

```
private void initializePlot(XYPlotZoomPan plot, int tick, SimpleXYSeries series) {
    plot.setDomainBoundaries(0, windowsize, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
    plot.addSeries(series, formatter);
    plot.setDrawRangeOriginEnabled(true);
    plot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(Constants.RANGE_TICKS);
    plot.setTicksPerDomainLabel(Constants.DOMAIN_TICKS);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeOriginTickLabelPaint().setTextSize(20);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeTickLabelPaint().setTextSize(20);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainOriginTickLabelPaint().setTextSize(20);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainTickLabelPaint().setTextSize(20);
    plot.getLegendWidget().setVisible(false);
    plot.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainOriginLinePaint().setColor(dkgrey);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainOriginTickLabelPaint().setColor(dkgrey);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeOriginTickLabelPaint().setColor(dkgrey);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeOriginLinePaint().setColor(dkgrey);
    plot.getTitleWidget().position(0, XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_RIGHT, 0,
            YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_TOP, AnchorPosition.RIGHT_TOP);
    plot.centerOnRangeOrigin(0);
    plot.setRangeBottomMax(-Constants.RANGE_MIN);
    plot.setRangeTopMin(Constants.RANGE_MIN);
    plot.setRangeStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, tick);
    plot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, Constants.DOMAIN_TICK);
    adjustRangewindow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix would be to add a style param to your plot's xml:

```
style="@style/APDefacto.Dark"
```

On a side note, you can optionally replace of the formatting you're doing in code with xml.  Additionally, there now exist formal styleable attrs for these params:

```
androidPlot.graphWidget.marginBottom="10dp"
androidPlot.graphWidget.marginLeft="10dp"
androidPlot.graphWidget.marginRight="10dp"
androidPlot.graphWidget.marginTop="10dp"
```

While these will continue to work, they rely on Configurator which is the older way of styling via xml.  Replace with:

```
ap:marginTop="10dp"
ap:marginBottom="10dp"
ap:marginLeft="10dp"
ap:marginRight="10dp"
```

The full list of styleable attrs available in 0.9.8 [can be found here](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/0.9.8/androidplot-core/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml).  The documentation for these attrs is sparse at the moment, but should get much better in the upcoming 1.0 release.

Comment: Nick adding the style param didn't work for me. And regarding the formatting I have given an option to change the theme.

Comment: as a debugging step could you try commenting out all of your custom formatting java / xml code (pretty much everything except the line that actually adds your series to the plot) while using the APDefacto.Dark style?

Comment: The issue is only when I use XYPlotZoomPan.

Comment: For now I'd suggest implementing your own zoom/pan behavior using the [TouchZoom example in the DemoApp](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/demoapp/src/main/java/com/androidplot/demos/TouchZoomExampleActivity.java) as a reference; XYPlotZoomPan was a 3rdparty contribution that has not been updated in quite some time.